# Alternative for Find_in_set which can use index

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a my sql stored procedure where i am passing a list of numbers as a comma separated mediumtext field

For checking if my parameter matched i am using Find_in_set in my stored procedure as follows

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS f1,f2,f3,f4 FROM `mytable`
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(f2,'1,2,4,5,6,6,7,8,8,4,9,7.......................') > 0
ORDER BY f1 DESC        
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
;

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Now problems with Find_in_set i found out later is that it doesn't used index due to which My query is taking too long to complete.
Please suggest any improvement in the query

P.S.

Following is my complete stored procedure (including the changes as suggested in below answer)

```
    DECLARE _calculated_offset INT;
    SET _calculated_offset = _limit * (_pageNumber -1);
    IF _calculated_offset < 0 THEN  
        SET _calculated_offset = 0;
    END IF;         

    /*SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS f1,f2,f3,f4  FROM `mytable`
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(f1,_telcoIdList) > 0  
    AND FIND_IN_SET(f2,_msisdnList) > 0 
    ORDER BY f3 DESC        
    LIMIT _limit OFFSET _calculated_offset
    ;

    SELECT FOUND_ROWS();*/


SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS f1,f2,f3,f4
    FROM `mytable`
    WHERE f1 in (',_telcoIdList,')
    AND f2 in (',_msisdnList,') 
    ORDER BY f3 DESC        
    LIMIT ', _limit,' OFFSET ',_calculated_offset,' ;

    SELECT FOUND_ROWS();

    '); 
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query; 
    EXECUTE stmt; 
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Why are you ordering by `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`?.. or is there a missing comma?

Comment: @Arth Please read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Comment: @Akhil, I know what it does.. just wondering why you would `ORDER BY` it.. it's currently aliased as `f1`

Comment: @Arth no. f1 is not an alias. It is a filed name. Syntax - `select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS col1, col2 from table`

Comment: @Akhil.. then you'll need a comma in between right? Hence my first comment.

Comment: @Arth I have edited my comment with syntax. it does not require any comma in between ..

Answer (score 1):

Use prepared statement and change to `in` clause

```
SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS f1,f2,f3,f4 FROM mytable
WHERE f2 in (', myinputstr, ') ORDER BY f1 DESC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0'); 

    PREPARE stmt FROM @query; 

    EXECUTE stmt; 

    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

This will allow the f2 index to be used.

EDIT : To include foundrows statement, use the following style

```
SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS f1,f2,f3,f4
    FROM `mytable`
    WHERE f1 in (',_telcoIdList,')
    AND f2 in (',_msisdnList,') 
    ORDER BY f3 DESC        
    LIMIT ', _limit,' OFFSET ',_calculated_offset); 
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query; 
    EXECUTE stmt; 
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 

    SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

BTW, added SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS too in the query

Comment: That won't 'force' an index to be used.. allow but not force. Plus the syntax  for `IN` is different to `FIND_IN_SET`.

Comment: `IN` requires each option to be a separate value

Comment: @Arth. I agree with your first point about index. Bad usage of "force"

Comment: Problem when adding SELECT FOUND_ROWS(); in the query

Comment: @KamranShahid Details pls. SELECT FOUND_ROWS(); need not be in the prepared statement. What is the error

Comment: error is you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT FOUND_ROWS()' at line 4
I have simply added SELECT FOUND_ROWS(); after ORDER BY f1 DESC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0;

Comment: Is it true that in prepared statement i can't use two queries ? If it is I will have performance impact as for total I might have to again query the table with count(*)

Comment: Please post your complete SP content

Comment: I have edited my post with new stored procedure body. @Akhil please check

Comment: @KamranShahid I have updated my answer with the complete procedure content

Comment: @Akhil looks like two queries in a single statement doesn't work. And if i place outside the prepare statment it doesn't give correct count. Like I actually have 59,000 records and it somehow gives result of 310

Comment: @KamranShahid did you add SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS in your first query?